# Getting data from nested children Firebase Realtimebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I've been using Firebase recently.
​
I have a question because there is a part that doesn't work well.
​
All I want is the total value of a, b, and c.

How much is a, how much is b, and how much is c?
​
It seems simple, but it doesn't work as I thought it would.

```
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
  override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
    for (snapshot in p0.children) {
      var ref = snapshot.key
      Log.d ("Test", snapshot.key) // get A,B,C,Name
      Gets the contents of the log.d("bell", p0.child("A").value.toString())) // A
    }
  }
});
```

​
We can get the sum of a, b, c in the above way, but I want to implement the fluid part.
​
There could be an H as well as a C, and I'd like to deal with the difference in the number of subtexts.
​
I've been thinking about Arraylist. I'm worried that it'll get more complicated if it's stored this way.
​
I'm writing to see if I can get some help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all the values that exist under each node, a, b, c, d, e, etc, no matter how many children are there, you need to query the database twice. So assuming that the "timedata" node is a direct child of your Firebase Realtime Database root, and that long id, is the UID of the logged-in users, please use the following lines of code:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val uidRef = rootRef.child("timedata").child(uid)
val valueEventListener: ValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        var total: Long = 0
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
            for (dSnapshot in ds.children) {
                val value = dSnapshot.getValue(Long::class.java)!!.toLong()
                total += value
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "total: $total")
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.message) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

And this is for Java users:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("timedata").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long total = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {
                long value = Long.parseLong(dSnapshot.getValue(Long.class));
                total += value;
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "total: " + total);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

According to your screenshot, the result in your logcat will be:

```
53032
```

Comment: You're so kind. Thank you.